# How to compile java to a jar in bash

Tags: java, bash, automation, compilation

I have a bunch of *.java files and I want to compile and package them into a jar file using a bash script that mainly does the following:

```
java_sources=$(find . -type f -name "*.java")
javac -g ${java_sources} -classpath ${JAVA_CLASSPATH}

java_classes=$(find . -type f -name "*.class")
jar cf ${JAVA_DIST}/${JAR_FILE} ${java_classes}

rm ${java_classes}
```

Is there a shorter way to perform these operations using java binaries and bash commands? I don't want to use any other automation tool such as maven etc.

Comment: In short, no there isn't.  This is why build tools were invented .... starting with Make.   (In 1976; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Origin)

Answer (score 0):

This is not shorter, but I fixed missing quotes and loopholes with filenames witch contains spaces, tabs or newlines or other non-printable characters:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -d '' java_sources < <(find . -type f -iname '*.java' -print0)
javac -g "${java_sources[@]}" -classpath "${JAVA_CLASSPATH}"

mapfile -d '' java_classes < <(find . -type f -iname '*.class' -print0)
jar cf "${JAVA_DIST}/${JAR_FILE}" "${java_classes[@]}"

rm -- "${java_classes[@]}"
```